# Unexpected output 1 in json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have been trying to print an output using `json_encode`, the code is below:

```
<?  
   $lid = $_GET['last_id'];

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_posts WHERE id < $lid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";

   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   $json = include('datam.php');

   echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Here is the datam.php file:

```
<?
$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$likes = $row['likes'];
$dislikes = $row['dislikes'];
$text = $row['text'];
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$title = substr($text, 0, 50);
$title = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $title);
$title = trim($title, '-');
$title = strtolower($title);
$title = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $title);
if(empty($title)) {
$title = "no-title";
}
$cat = $row['cat'];
$cat = strtolower($cat);
$cat = str_replace(" ","-",$cat);
$ccat = str_replace("-"," ",$cat);
$ccat = ucwords($ccat);
$by = $row['uid'];
$dt = $row['date'];
$tm = $row['time'];
$time = strtotime("$dt $tm");
$nsfw = $row['nsfw'];
if ($nsfw == 1)
$isnsfw = '<span class="nsfw">NSFW</span>';
else
$isnsfw = "";

// Time Ago

// Get OP
$suser = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE id = $by";
$muser = mysqli_query($con,$suser);
$guser = mysqli_fetch_array($muser);
$byuser = $guser['user'];
$byuser = strtolower($byuser);
$byuser = str_replace(" ","-",$byuser);
$cbyuser = str_replace("-"," ",$byuser);
$cbyuser = ucwords($cbyuser);

// WhatsApp Link
$wm = preg_replace("/\n/", "%0A", $text);

if($count == 5 && $cnsfw == 0) {
include "adapp.php";
}

echo '<div class="box" id="'.$id.'"><div class="t">Posted by <a href="/profile/'.$byuser.'">'.$cbyuser.'</a> in <a href="/cat/'.$cat.'">'.$ccat.'</a> '.ago($time).' ago</div><div class="m">'.$text.'</div><div class="m"><span class="col-3"><span class="likes">'.$likes.' Likes</span></span><span class="col-3"><span class="dislikes">'.$dislikes.' Dislikes</span></span><span class="col-3">'.$isnsfw.'</span></div><div class="b"><span class="col-5 l bbox"><img src="/img/like.png" /></span><span class="col-5 l bbox"><img src="/img/dislike.png" /></span><span class="col-5 l bbox"><a href="/msg/'.$id.'/'.$title.'"><img src="/img/comment.png" /></a></span><span class="col-5 l bbox"><a rel="nofollow" href="whatsapp://send?text=http://whatsappstatus.in/msg/'.$id.'%0A'.$wm.'"><img src="/img/whatsapp.png" /></a></span><span class="col-5 l bbox"><img src="/img/options.png" /></span></div><div class="clr"></div></div>';
$count++;
}
?>
```

Using this code, all the output appears as expected but, at the end of each output, there is unexpected output `1` which has no source of origin.

Every time this code executes, it gives an unexpected 1 at the end and I can't seem to find where it is coming from.

Here is the picture of sample output:

[image]

You can visit this URL to check it: http://funpd.com/messages1

Comment: as i seen your link i came to know after every 10 element that '1' get print.I think it might u have echo some value in your loop. can u please show the code from where your data is being loaded.What about your `datam.php` and `adapp.php`

Comment: @Niyanta the data is being loaded using `datam.php`, which is included in the question and the `adapp.php` is nothing but a adsense ad code.

Comment: what about `adapp.php`

Comment: @Niyanta it's a adsense ad code

Comment: have check after commenting that adsense code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using

```
$json = include('datam.php');
```

In your datam.php you should `return` the value of the data you want assigning to `$json` rather than echoing it out.  The echo in the datam.php is code which is displaying the data and the 1 is the value being assigned to `$json` (which is the value returned by your datam.php page).

You can test this by commenting out the echo in the sub page and you should just see the value 1 being displayed.

It may be the easiest solution looking at your code to just include this sub-page and not assign the value to `$json`, but you may have a reason for json encoding the return value.

**Update**:
To batch data up, build an array of data.  At the top

```
$output = [];
```

After your echo - build an array of the results and add it to output array...

```
$output[] = [$id, $byuser, $cbyuser, ...];
```

(You will need to complete this with all of the fields you need)

And at the end

```
return $output;
```

This will pass all the data back to the calling page.

Comment: Returning value is a good solution but there's a problem. As you can see, I am echoing the data in `while` loop, so there are multiple values to return and I think returning multiple values is not possible.

Comment: I've added a way of creating a result set, not sure if this is instead of the echo or as well, but see if it helps.